# Is there a nice phrase for 'flaw in the process'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a nice phrase for conveying the meaning that 'flaw in the process'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [*a fly in the ointment*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fly+in+the+ointment)?

You could also say, [*a hitch in the plan*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hitch).

Comment: My 11th grade math teacher, who was quite bright but something of an autodidact from a rough background, would always say "There's a flaw in the ointment".  (But "fly in the ointment" is the correct idiom.)

Comment: @HotLicks - That's better than *there's a fly in the plan*, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, but the far more common situation, for young guys, is to have a plan in their fly.  (Though very few of them make it through to realization.)

Comment: @HotLicks - Haha, indeed. I'm sure there's a joke about ointment in there somewhere too.

Comment: Reminds me of that old limerick that ends "for in their haste they used library paste instead of Vaseline".  Alas, can't remember the rest of it.

Comment: @HotLicks - I just found a *... petroleum jelly* version, it was rather good.

Comment: The *petroleum jelly* version is a weak imitation of the real one.  (Or at least that's what I remember -- it's been 50 years.)